# ExtJS 4 - how to hide context menu when left clicking the Ext.panel.Panel?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have context menu on a panel (geoext 2 map panel)
This is how I init it :

```
 var ctxMenu;

   Ext.get("mapPanel-body").on("contextmenu", function (event, element) {
        event.stopEvent();
        if (!ctxMenu) {
            ctxMenu = Ext.create('Ext.menu.Menu', {
            width:100,
            height:100,
            margin: '0 0 10 0',        
            items: [{ text: 'test', action: 'test'}]
    });
        }
        ctxMenu.showAt(event.getXY());
        return false;
    });
```

What happens is that right click on the map opens the context menu ... but it stays open till I choose an item from the menu (left click outside it doesnt close it)

I'm using ExtJS 4.2.1

Why it behaves like this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be the reason is , panel doesnot contain a default contextMenu event.

But you are defining a contextMenu by using the **on** on the panel.

For this issue you can define a click event for the panel by using the same **on** config and check whether the object **contextMenu** is present or not.

If it is present , then hide the contextMenu by using contextMenuObject.hide().

Comment: the panel on click didn't work , but I added click event to the openlayers component. so I accept your answer :-)